# Memory Leak in this code?

Tags: c++

Sample here:

```
class A
{
private:
    int buff[1000];
public:
    A(int n)
    {
        buff = new int[n];
    }
};

 int main()
 {
     for (int i = 10; i < 1000; i++)
     {
         A a(i);
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Can anyone help me? what's wrong with this code? Memory Leak? Or any other errors?

Comment: Yes, obviously. You have a `new` without a matching `delete`.

Comment: A memory leak should be the least of your worries. This code doesn't even compile.

Comment: If it doesn't compile, it doesn't leak, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the issues pointed out in the comments, you should create a destructor which calls [`delete[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) on the item you allocated on the heap (using the `new` keyword):

```
class A{
   private:
       int buff[1000];
   public:
       A(int n){
           buff=new int[n];
       }
       ~A() {
           delete[] buff;
       }
};

int main(){
    for(int i=10;i<1000;i++){
        A a(i);
     }   
     return 0;
}
```

Don't forget the `[]` after the `delete` because it's an array.

Comment: That still won't compile. Arrays aren't assignable.

Comment: @0x499602D2, well, tigerrussell says "side from the issues pointed out in the comments" ...

Comment: @Kay There are no other specific issues pointed out in the comments. The OP didn't know that arrays aren't assignable.

Comment: Change that `int buff[1000];` to `int* buff;` and it'd be good. Not great, but at least valid.

Comment: Well, I really did mean "aside from the fact it won't compile." The only thing I cared about demonstrating was the use of destructors and `delete[]`. OP can figure the rest out - s/he is an adult.. maybe.

Comment: By the way OP you should check out http://codepad.org/ for typing up simple examples -- it will help you avoid scenarios where the code you posted won't compile.

Comment: That fixes the memory leak, but gives it invalid copy semantics: it will explode horribly if you accidentally copy an object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722

Answer (score 0):

Modern C++ says you should be using `new` or `delete` in your code at all, but rather `std::unique_ptr` which does your memory management for you.

As such, your class would fit modern idioms better in this way:

```
#include <memory>

class A
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> buff;
public:
    A(int n)
        : buff(std::make_unique(int[n])) // buff(new int[n]) if using C++11
    { }
};

int main()
{
    A a(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately `std::make_unique` isn't available in C++11, so until then you have to use `new`. However, you can still use `std::unique_ptr`, which will solve your memory leak issue.